# Add computed property to Route.Extend in Ember

Tags: ember.js

So I have a main.js file which is a route:

```
import user from 'config/user';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Route.extend(SomeMixin, {
    firstName: computed(function () {
       return user.firstName;
    },
}),
```

in my hbs file I have `{{firstName}}`

firstName is always empty in my hbs file. Is it possible to add a computed function to a route?

Answer (score 2):

The `this` context of route's template is not the `Route` instance but the `Controller` associated with that route. If there isn't any controller defined explicitly, Ember will create one implicitly. By default the route only sets the return value of `model` hook on that controller as `model` property. This is done in `setupController` hook.

Long story short: You should generate a controller for your route using Ember CLI `ember generate controller my-route` and move your property to that one. After doing so it will be available on `this` context of route's template.

In general the route is only meant for serializing and deserializing application state. All logic should be moved to the controller or components (or services consumed by them).